# Reading variables from txt file

Tags: php, forms, session, post

New to php. I am building some html forms and want to create session. The method I am using for passing variables is `post`.

I have lot of variables, so I am creating a text file and reading the content of the file as `fgets()` and passing it through following loop.

One of those varibles is `name` for which I enetered value as `abc`.

If I write `echo $_POST["name"]` , it is giving me the correct output as `abc`.

When I write `echo fgets(my_file_name)`, it is giving me output as `name`; which is correct.

But when I write `echo $_POST[fgets(my_file_name)]` it gives me error as `Undefined index: name`.

Then I tried converting the output of `fgets(my_file_name)` to string like this: `$variable = strval(fgets(my_file_name))`. Still `echo $_POST[$variable]` generates an error.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Are you creating a text file for each session? Any reason you can write your file as php code and then just include it?

Comment: Just a hunch: Try doing `echo $_POST[trim(fgets(my_file_name))]`

Comment: I feel the same as Jason. You could store all the variables in an array like this: `$expectedPostVariables = array('name','field2','field3','field4');`

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I created a php file and created the array having all the  post variables. Thanks.